# std::tuple of std::shared_ptr of template parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I want to implement a class template that:

1. behaves like a function
2. it's input and output variables are all shared.
3. relatively easy to use.

As a result, I construct the following:

```
// all input/output variable's base class
class basic_logic_parameter;

// input/output variable, has theire value and iterators to functions that reference to this variable
template <typename FuncIterator, typename ValueType>
class logic_parameter
    :public basic_logic_parameter
{
private:
    std::list<FuncIterator> _refedFuncs;
    ValueType _val;
public:

};

// all `function`'s base class
class basic_logic_function
{
public:
    virtual ~basic_logic_function() = 0;
};

// the function, has input/output variable
template <typename FuncIterator, typename R, typename... Args>
class logic_function_base
    :public basic_logic_function
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<logic_parameter<FuncIterator, R>> _ret;
    std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<logic_parameter<FuncIterator, Args>>...> _args;
public:
    template <std::size_t N>
    decltype(auto) arg()
    {
        return std::get<N>(_args);
    }

    template <std::size_t N>
    struct arg_type
    {
        typedef std::tuple_element_t<N> type;
    };

    template <std::size_t N>
    using arg_type_t = arg_type<N>::type;

    decltype(auto) ret()
    {
        return _ret;
    }
};
```

I wish to use as these like:

```
// drawing need  color and a pen
    struct Color
    {
    };

    struct Pen
    {
    };

    struct Iter
    {
    };

    class Drawer
        :public logic_function_base<Iter, void(Color, Pen)>
    {
    public:
        void draw()
        {
            arg_type_t<0> pColor; // wrong
        }
    }
```

My compiler can not pass this code through, why? I just want convert a template parameter pack to `std::tuple of std::shared_ptr of them.`
for example:

Given `struct A, int, struct C`, I want to have:

```
std::tuple<
  std::shared_ptr<logic_parameter<A>>,
  std::shared_ptr<logic_parameter<int>>,
  std::shared_ptr<logic_parameter<C>>,
>
```

Comment: There are obvious errors in your code (missing `tuple` for `std::tuple_element_t` or missing `typename`), are these copy/paste errors?

Comment: `R(Args...)` is not magically expanded into `typename R, typename... Args` on its own, perpahs [use a partial specialization and fix a couple of errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9c5cd84502ef962)

Comment: @Holt it's a typing error:)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I will try it later. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem (once the small errors are fixed<sup>1</sup>) is that you instantiate:

```
logic_function_base<Iter, void(Color, Pen)>
```

...meaning that `FuncIterator` is `Iter` and `R` is `void(Color, Pen)`, so `Args` is emtpy `<>`, so `decltype(_args)` is an empty `std::tuple<>`, and your code fails to obtain the type of the 0th element of an empty tuple, which is legit.

What you want is partial specialization of `logic_function_base`:

```
template <typename F, typename T>
class logic_function_base;


template <typename FuncIterator, typename R, typename... Args>
class logic_function_base<FuncIterator, R(Args...)>: public basic_logic_function {

};
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Small mistakes in your current code:

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct arg_type
{
    typedef std::tuple_element_t<N, decltype(_args)> type; // Missing the tuple type
};

template <std::size_t N>
using arg_type_t = typename arg_type<N>::type; // Missing a typename
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer your whole question, but you could use the following trait to wrap tuple element types.

```
template <typename T> struct wrap;
template <typename... T>
struct wrap<std::tuple<T...>> {
  using type = std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<logic_parameter<T>>...>;
}
template <typename T>
using wrap_t = typename wrap<T>::type;
```

You can then use it like this:

```
std::tuple<int,double,char> t1;
wrap_t<decltype(t)> t2;
```

The type of `t2` is `std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<logic_parameter<int>>,std::shared_ptr<logic_parameter<double>>,std::shared_ptr<logic_parameter<char>>>`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Comment: @ChungkingExpress It is customary on stackoverflow to upvote, rather than thanking in the comments. But you are welcome. Cheers.